# How do I set line spacing inside BIRT Report Designer

Tags: report, birt

I am new to using BIRT report designer. Our organisation brand guidline stipulates that all letters need to have line spacing of exact 15pt. And they go further and show us how to set this setting in Microsoft Word:

[image: paragraph settings in MS Word 2016]

Now I am trying to set this in my reports that are created using BIRT, but for the life of me I cannot see where this setting if found?

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

My report is setup as follows:

[image: BIRT object types]

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

select the text box that you want to add the letter spacing, go to the Advanced options and inside the Text Property set the Letter Spacing as shown:

[image]

Comment: Not quite correct. Advanced options is the right place to look at, but "Letter spacing" if for adding extra horizontal space betwwen letters, to achieve an effect like T I T L E . What you really need to set is "Line height".